# Nonnegative solution for wave equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the following boundary problems for the wave equation:
$$\begin{cases} u_{tt}=u_{xx},\; (x,t)\in (0,\pi)\times (0,\infty) \\ u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0,\; t\geq 0 \\ u(x,0)=g(x),\; x\in [0,\pi] \\ u_t(x,0)=0,\; x\in [0,\pi] \end{cases} (*) \quad \quad  \begin{cases} u_{tt}=u_{xx},\; (x,t)\in (0,\pi)\times (0,\infty) \\ u_x(0,t)=u_x(\pi,t)=0,\; t\geq 0 \\ u(x,0)=g(x),\; x\in [0,\pi] \\ u_t(x,0)=0,\; x\in [0,\pi] \end{cases}(**) $$
where $g\in C^2([0,\pi])$.

I was asked to solve these two questions:

a) In $(*)$, if $g(0)=g(\pi)=0$ and $g\geq0$, then $u\geq0$.

b) In $(**)$, if $g'(0)=g'(\pi)=0$ and $g\geq0$, then $u\geq0$.

For a), I proved that it is not true. Solving by separation of variables, the only possible solution has the form $$u(x,t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k\cos(kt)\sin(kx),\quad a_k=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} g(x)\sin(kx)\,dx.$$ Then, if $g(x)=\sin x$, we have $g\geq0$ on $[0,\pi]$ and $u(x,t)=\sin x\cos t$, so for example $u(\pi/4,3\pi/4)=(1/\sqrt{2})(-1/\sqrt{2})<0$.

For b), using separation of variables again, the only possible solution has the form $$u(x,t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k\cos(kt)\cos(kx),\quad a_k=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} g(x)\cos(kx)\,dx.$$ Looking at some functions $g$, I was not able to find $u<0$ at some point, so I think b) should be true. However, I cannot prove this. For instance, looking at the explicit solution, since $a_k$ and $\cos$ may take any sign, I cannot proceed. I also tried by contradiction assuming that there is a minimum of $u$ smaller than $0$, and then use that $\nabla u$ at that minimum is $0$ and $\Delta u$ at that point is $\geq0$, but nothing.

Could you provide any hint to solve b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve (**) in a different way.

Extend the initial value to $[\pi,2\,\pi]$ by parity ($g(x)=g(x-\pi)$,) and then to all of $\Bbb R$ by periodicity. The initial value for $u_t(x,0)$ is extended to be equal to $0$ on $\Bbb R$. Then the solution of the problem is given by $u(x,t)=g(x+t)+g(x-t)$. Since $g\ge0$, so is $u$.